# Android : initialise array

Tags: android, arrays

Im trying to fill a list view with Strings retrieved from a webService and seems like my array is initially empty I know that I should initialise it but can any body give me a hint how to? this is my code :

```
public class TunisAirports extends Fragment {
    ListView List;
    String[] Name;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tunis_airports, container, false);

        List = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.TNairp);
        final ArrayList<Airport> listAirport = new ArrayList<Airport>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listAirport.size(); i++) {
            Airport airport = listAirport.get(i);
            String AirName = airport.getname();
        }

        String Airport_URL = AppConfig.URL_GET_AIRPORT;
        Log.d("URL Airport", Airport_URL);
        String tag_string_req = "airport";
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            Airport_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jo = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jo.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jObj = jo.getJSONObject(i);
                            Airport new_airport = new Airport();
                            new_airport.setname(jObj.getString("airport_name"));

                            Name[i] = new_airport.getname();
                        }


                        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            R.layout.row_airport,
                            R.id.lbl_name,
                            Name);

                        List.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("dynamic Error: ", error.getMessage());
                }
            });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq,
            tag_string_req);
    }
}
```

My Model :

```
public class Airport {

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;

    @SerializedName("city")
    public String city;

    @SerializedName("country")
    public String country;

    @SerializedName("iata")
    public String iata;

    @SerializedName("icao")
    public String icao;

    @SerializedName("latitude")
    public String latitude;

    @SerializedName("longitude")
    public String longitude;

    @SerializedName("altitude")
    public String altitude;

    @SerializedName("timezone")
    public String timeZone;

    @SerializedName("dst")
    public String dst;

    @SerializedName("Image")
    public String Image;

    @SerializedName("Description")
    public String Description;

    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;

    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return Image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.Image = image;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.Description = description;
    }

    public String getid() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setid(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Im getting `NullPointerException` in this line:

> Name[i] = new_airport.getname();

Comment: Dude, initialize Name Array as before for-loop:  `Name=new String[jo.length()];`

Comment: why are u setting new_airport.getname(); 
you can directly  add Name[i]=jObj.getString("airport_name")

Comment: Avoid arrays, just use an ArrayList which dynamically resizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see there is no conditional check for null or anything for `jo.length()`, you can use that directly to initialize your array as

```
String[] Name = new String[jo.length()];
```

Another approach is to use `List<String> liAirportName`, in this you do not have to worry about the lenght, you can simply do

```
List<String> liAirportName = new ArrayList<String>();
liAirportName.add(new_airport.getname());
```

Ones you are done with adding all the Airport names, if you wish you can use `liAirportName` directly or else convert it to array as below

```
String[] Name = liAirportName.toArray(new String[liAirportName.size()]);
```

Comment: I used the second approach

it's giving this error now without giving the line : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: did you add `Airport new_airport = new Airport(); new_airport.setname(jObj.getString("airport_name"));` before liAirportName.add(new_airport.getname());

Comment: issue is you did `Airport new_airport = new Airport();` before `ArrayList<String> liAirportName = new ArrayList<String>();` but then without calling `new_airport.setname()`, you called `liAirportName.add(new_airport.getname());`